# Rails IF Statement Not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to conditionally show a link based upon some fields in the database, however, neither is set according to the IF statement and the link is showing anyway.

```
<% if :mobile.present? && :mobile_verified != true %>
    <%= link_to "(Verify Mobile)", :controller => 'users', :action => 'resend_verification', :method=> :post %>
<% end %>
```

Is something incorrect?

Comment: Those are symbols, not variables.  You probably want to remove the `:`.  Perhaps you meant to prefix them with `@`.

Comment: Many thanks!  Why can't I mark your solution as the answer?

Comment: b/c it was a comment :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are symbols, not variables. You probably want to remove the `:`. Perhaps you meant to prefix them with `@`, which would be the case if they were instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `:`, it declare [ruby symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Symbol.html). and when you variable begins with sign `@` indicates that they are [instance variables](http://ruby.about.com/od/variables/a/Instance-Variables.htm).

In general scenario we define instance variables in controller and then we use them in view file. So I guess your code should be like this:

```
<% if @mobile.present? && @mobile_verified != true %>
    <%= link_to "(Verify Mobile)", :controller => 'users', :action => 'resend_verification', :method=> :post %>
<% end %>
```

Don't forget to set these variables `@mobile` and `@mobile_verified` before using them in above code

Comment: The _if @mobile.present?_ part does not seem to be working...it's defined as _@mobile = @user.mobile_ in the controller..._@user_ is defined as _@user = current_user_

Comment: What error comes on `@mobile.present?`.
Or pasting the stack trace from console would do.

Comment: No error message, just no link and the conditions are being met as far as I can tell, http://pastebin.com/0GzSgH8r

Comment: As you said you have defined `@mobile = @user.mobile` and `@mobile.inspect` shows nil. This means your `@user.mobile` is nil.

Now I don't know if `mobile` is method or attribute. But if it's attribute then you have to set some value for it.Otherwise if it's a method and you think it should return some value then method's logic must be wrong.

Comment: Had to go with @user.mobile.present? instead.